# Opening Firebase Dynamic Link from Facebook to App instead of Facebook web preview

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented Firebase Dynamic links in React-Native app. They are working fine for both Android & iOS, but from Facebook App link is not being redirect to App.
It would be really nice of you, if you help me with that regards.
Thank you.

## reactnative #firebase #dynamiclinks

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, since last Friday the dynamic links are no longer open passing through the facebook webview. It was probably blocked by facebook.